# Error compiling extension methods with Kotlin 1.4.10

Tags: kotlin

I don't use Kotlin on a daily basis so I might missed changes between `1.3.72` and `1.4.10`. Fact is, code that used to compile with the older version now breaks with the newer. Case in point this file https://github.com/griffon/griffon/blob/development/subprojects/griffon-javafx-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/griffon/javafx/kotlin/collections/reduce/ReducingBindingsExtension.kt
produces lost of errors such as

```
e: /Users/aalmiray/dev/github/griffon/subprojects/griffon-javafx-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/griffon/javafx/kotlin/collections/reduce/ReducingBindingsExtension.kt: (59, 29): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun <T : Any!> reduceThenMapToBoolean(p0: ObservableList<TypeVariable(T)!>!, p1: TypeVariable(T)!, p2: BinaryOperator<TypeVariable(T)!>!, p3: Function<in TypeVariable(T)!, Boolean!>!): BooleanBinding! defined in griffon.javafx.beans.binding.ReducingBindings
public open fun <T : Any!> reduceThenMapToBoolean(p0: ObservableList<TypeVariable(T)!>!, p1: TypeVariable(T)!, p2: ObservableValue<BinaryOperator<TypeVariable(T)!>!>!, p3: ObservableValue<Function<in TypeVariable(T)!, Boolean!>!>!): BooleanBinding! defined in griffon.javafx.beans.binding.ReducingBindings
public open fun <T : Any!> reduceThenMapToBoolean(p0: ObservableList<TypeVariable(T)!>!, p1: Supplier<TypeVariable(T)!>!, p2: BinaryOperator<TypeVariable(T)!>!, p3: Function<in TypeVariable(T)!, Boolean!>!): BooleanBinding! defined in griffon.javafx.beans.binding.ReducingBindings
public open fun <T : Any!> reduceThenMapToBoolean(p0: ObservableList<TypeVariable(T)!>!, p1: Supplier<TypeVariable(T)!>!, p2: ObservableValue<BinaryOperator<TypeVariable(T)!>!>!, p3: ObservableValue<Function<in TypeVariable(T)!, Boolean!>!>!): BooleanBinding! defined in griffon.javafx.beans.binding.ReducingBindings
public open fun <K : Any!, V : Any!> reduceThenMapToBoolean(p0: ObservableMap<TypeVariable(K)!, TypeVariable(V)!>!, p1: TypeVariable(V)!, p2: BinaryOperator<TypeVariable(V)!>!, p3: Function<in TypeVariable(V)!, Boolean!>!): BooleanBinding! defined in griffon.javafx.beans.binding.ReducingBindings
```

The full list of errors can be found at https://gist.github.com/aalmiray/e17662a1ffae53006b2f633a35bfec02

Is there a different idiom in Kotlin 1.4 that must be used to write extension functions? What am I missing? TIA.

**UPDATE:** MCVE can be found at https://github.com/aalmiray/kotlin-mcve. The error is different but the effect is the same, code compiles with `1.3.72` but breaks with `1.4.10`.

MCVE project structure

```
.
├── README.md
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                └── acme
                    ├── ReducingBindings.java
                    └── ReducingBindingsExtension.kt
```

settings.gradle

```
// empty
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.10'
}

ext.kotlinVersion = '1.4.10'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

ReducingBindings.java

```
package com.acme;

import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;

import static javafx.beans.binding.Bindings.createBooleanBinding;

public class ReducingBindings {

    public static <T> BooleanBinding reduceThenMapToBoolean(final ObservableList<T> items, final T defaultValue, final BinaryOperator<T> reducer, final Function<? super T, Boolean> mapper) {
        return createBooleanBinding(() -> mapper.apply(items.stream().reduce(reducer).orElse(defaultValue)), items);
    }

}
```

ReducingBindingsExtension.kt

```
package com.acme

import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding
import javafx.collections.ObservableList
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator
import java.util.function.Function

fun <T> ObservableList<T>.reduceThenMapToBoolean(defaultValue: T?, reducer: BinaryOperator<T>, mapper: Function<in T, Boolean>): BooleanBinding {
    return ReducingBindings.reduceThenMapToBoolean(this, defaultValue, reducer, mapper)
}
```

Run it with Java 8 and Gradle 6. Or you know, just clone the repo from https://github.com/aalmiray/kotlin-mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a different idiom in Kotlin 1.4 that must be used to write extension functions?

No it is the same. But they introduced [new type inference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#new-more-powerful-type-inference-algorithm) mechanism, maybe this is the case.

When I changed type of `mapper` parameter from `Function<in T, Boolean>` to `Function<in T?, Boolean>` in provided example, it compiled!

Comment: Thanks. That small change makes the code work, both for the MCVE and the original problem at the Griffon codebase.